# RxJava Android - replace list with map or flatmap

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am pretty new to RxJava

I have an Observable

```
  private static rx.Observable<List<item>> getList() {
        return rx.Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            call some internal methods
            return list;
        });
    }
```

I have a caller method

```
public static void getListFromObservable() {
        getList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe( new Subscriber<List<item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<item> i) {
                    for (item each : i) {
                           getSubdetails(each)
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                          .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {

                           @Override
                           public void onCompleted() {}
                           @Override
                           public void onError(Throwable error) {  }
                           @Override
                           public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {}
                   });
      }
```

This is another observable

```
private static rx.Observable<Boolean>> getSubdetails(item i) {
            return rx.Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                call some internal methods
                return true;
            });
        }
```

I do not want to use foreach in the OnNext, but I want to use Map or FlatMaps. Can someone help me on how to do this?

Comment: I'd stay with the for each.  Every chain you add on makes the code less readable and maintainable  in the future.  This is much clearer to understand.

Comment: Thought of using Maps or FlatMaps to see how the code can be shortened. Just want to learn and give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
getList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
    .flatMap(each -> getSubdetails(each))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Trying your code worked perfectly. I understood that flatMapIterable holds the collection and flatMap does the foreach of the collection. How to use flatMapIterable for 'Single'. As I want to change getList() Observable to Single. As it only emits one List at one time.

Comment: On 1.x, you can use `Single.flatMapObservable(list -> Observable.from(list))`. On 2.x, you can use [`Single.flattenAsObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) or `flattenAsFlowable`.

Comment: I ran into two problems - 
getList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapObservable(list -> Observable.from(list))
    .flatMap(each -> getSubdetails(each)) // ***no instance of type variable  R exist so that single<Boolean> conforms to Observable<? extends R> ***//
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new SingleSubscrible<Boolean>){ onSuccess and onError}; //**cannot resolve method subscribe**//

Comment: Subscribe with `rx.Subscriber` instead of `SingleSubscriber`.

Comment: If I write rx.subscriber, it is normal subscriber, right? I am getting three methods in it onNext, Error, Complete. But I will only need success and error.

Comment: Since you have multiple list items, you will get multiple Booleans you have to consume with a Subscriber.

Comment: Ok, and I also updated my grade to RxJava2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
getListObservable()
    ...
    .flatMap( listOfItems ->
        return Observable.fromIterable(listOfItems)
                    .concatMap(item -> getDetailsObservable(item))
                    .toList()
                    .toObservable()
    )
    .doOnNext { detailedListOfItems ->
        // Do Something with your detailed items
    }
```

There is a good book for beginners in RxJava https://www.manning.com/books/rxjava-for-android-developers
I am not shore about the architect in that book. Especially with ViewModel, but many cool operators are explained very intuitive and graphically.

Difference between map and flatMap i finally understand with this book.